# get woocommerce cart quantity sum

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to use the sum of the quantity of all cart items to create button or page link options. So if cart quantity sum was 1 then this would conditionally display a button that I could add a custom link to. Similarly, if the quantity sum was 2. 3 or 4plus then a button for each of these would conditionally show.
The purpose is to avoid having to display all four buttons and so only display the relevant button determined by the cart quantity sum. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<?php
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
$totalquantity = 0;
foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
   $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id()); 
   $totalquantity += $values['quantity']; 
} 

if( $totalquantity ==0  ){
   return;
}
$link = '';
switch ($totalquantity) {
   case 2:
      $link = 'link URL 2';
      break;
   case 3:
      $link = 'link URL 3';
      break;
   case 4:
      $link = 'link URL 4';
      break;
   default:
      $link = 'link URL 1';
      break;
}

if( !empty($link )){
   echo "<a href='".$link."' >Button Text</a>";
}   
?>
```